# Error: Could not import settings 'app' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings on Local

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error

```
Error: Could not import settings 'app_name.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

I'm running a development local server and it stopped worked after I made some 400 inserts. Any pointers as to what caused this? The files are there and permissions are correct.

**Update:**

I've tried reverting back to a commit a few days old when it worked, but it still doesn't.

Comment: "A local server"? You mean the development server?

Comment: yes, manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the project folder to another directory, deleted .DStore as well, and copied the folder back, and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?:

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=your_settings_file_name
```